# design issue when no textbox delimiter is present

Tags: asp.net

I Got a design question pertaining to just my issue. My client asked me to have just 1 big text box in a pop up.Beneath it i have labels that user can see(Equipname,(LL,BB,PA),ClientName,Personnel). So he has to enter equipment name,either of(LL,BB,PA) ,cname,pname. An example row can look like "75 LL XYZCompany John". There is no delimiter between the entries. How can I make sure he is entering the corresponding values correctly.  I mean instead of entering "XYZCompanyname" , he enters "John" and for john he enters xyzcompanyname..what then?I gave them multiple textboxes first,but they did not want it. any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I see no way of validating or ensuring the integrity of what is entered by only using one textbox for multiple fields, especially without some kind delimiter.

From experience with non-technical clients who sometimes want odd implementations like this, my suggestion would be to stick to your guns and provide proper input fields that you can validate and explain clearly to them the consequences that having invalid data can have.

Not to mention that when implementing it the way the customer wants it now and when it inevitably falls apart, the fingers are going to be pointed at you for 'not doing your job' correctly.